# How to know which APK package installed a file in android?

Tags: android, linux, arm, apk

I'm currently at the shell prompt of Samsung Galaxy S2 ( Android 4.0.4 ). The system is not rooted. I'm currently interested in a few shared library files in /system/lib. I need to know which android package ( .APK ) installed a particular shared library. I need some command like the debian one below:

```
[ user@debian:~ ] $ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Here, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 was installed by "libc6" debian package.

Is there a equivalent of this in android APK environment ?

Comment: If the `.so` is in `/system/lib/`, no app installed it -- AFAIK, those would be part of the firmware. APKs' `.so` files go in `/data` along with the app itself.

Comment: Indeed, no application can have installed those (to a secured device), but the libraries for apps packaged on the system partition (and some app-like components of the system itself) will be found *somewhere* on the system partition.  For purely native code you would have to consult the build system or deduce it from the file name.  But JNI code will typically have function names discoverable with the ndk's `objdump` or `nm` which encode the Java class and package name they are associated with.  That is **not** necessarily the same as the package name of the owning apk, but it is a clue.